# WIN10 - How to forbid users to change their desktop items using active directory GPOs

Tags: windows-10, desktop, active-directory, group-policy

I would like to set up a GPO so users cannot edit, delete, add or rename desktop items anymore.

So far I activated:

```
user config
- guidelines
-- administrative templates
--- desktop
---- desktop
----- don't allow changes ON
----- don't allow adding of elements ON
----- don't allow deleting of elements ON
----- don't allow editing of elements ON
--- control panel
---- adaption
----- don't allow changes of desktopsymbols ON
```

Comment: What's the end goal here?

What should be on their Desktop? 

What about items on Explorer? That's even hard to close.

Answer (score 0):

Fully locking down the desktop is complicated.
You will find a very long list of policies to enable in the article
[Lock Down Desktop Using Group Policy](https://thebeardedgeek.com/2014/06/25/lock-desktop-using-group-policy/).

Here is the list that pertains directly to the desktop
(but there are lots more that are indirectly related):

- Do not add shares of recently opened documents to Network Locations
- Hide and disable all items on the desktop
- Hide Network Locations icon on desktop
- Prevent adding, dragging, dropping and closing the Taskbar’s toolbars
- Prohibit adjusting desktop toolbars
- Prohibit User from manually redirecting Profile Folders
- Remove Computer icon on the desktop
- Remove My Documents icon on the desktop
- Remove Properties from the Computer icon context menu
- Remove Properties from the Documents icon context menu
- Remove Properties from the Recycle Bin context menu
- Remove Recycle Bin icon from desktop
- Remove the Desktop Cleanup Wizard

Comment: If they dont allowed to be to do anything, did you ever thought about the Windows Kiosk Mode? - Remind if this mode is used, it will be not more possible to use anything else on that